# for loop in PostgreSQL ( for loop from two tables)

Tags: postgresql

I need to write a PostgreSQL  ( For each) function to process through column in one table and return another data from another table , are there  any solution to write function in postgresql loop with another variable?
hence what i want to make in pseudo_code format

```
for r in select subject_id from patientswithallmeasurement

{

begin
  select chartevents.subject_id,chartevents.charttime,chartevents.value, chartevents.valuenum
  from chartevents where chartevents.itemid in (211,220045,618,220210,220277)

r++

exit when r> 22900
endloop

}
```

if you ask why i didn't use sub-query, it returns to big data size

i try the following subquery as follows but it take average one hour and finally it stoped and  give "heap jdbc error",   when i make limit condition it gives just few number of features

```
select  chartevents.subject_id, chartevents.charttime,chartevents.value,
chartevents.valuenum,chartevents.itemid,chartevents.icustay_id
from chartevents 
WHERE chartevents.itemid In (211,220045,618,220210,220277,220050)
 and chartevents.subject_id IN 
    (   SELECT patient_features.subject_id
        FROM   patient_features where
        chartevents.subject_id=patient_features.subject_id

     )
```

Comment: A sub-query will most certainly be more efficient than a loop. But I have to admit I don't understand what exactly you are trying to achieve with that. `itemid in (and itemid in (..)` makes no sense to me

Comment: sorry , i update it , i not able to use sub-query as the data is  very big  , i cant get the results i want with sub-query, so that i want to try for each function

Comment: A sub-query has no limitation on the size of the result. If you have a performance problem, you should [edit] your question and add the query that gives you the problem

Comment: I don't see how the body of your loop depends on `r`.

Comment: you can check now , i have edit it @Hristo Iliev

Comment: i add the query that take the very long time with subquery method @a-horse-with-no-name

Comment: If you are getting a memory error in java, maybe try adjusting the fetch size.  You could also limit the results in the subselect, which is essentially what you are trying to do when you stop your loop.  In SQL, a loop is very rarely the correct answer and I'm very skeptical that it's correct here.